# android runtimeException error inflating fragment xml file line #17

Tags: android, android-fragments, runtimeexception, inflate-exception

Our teacher asked us to build to activities that hold the same fragment. After a load of errors and reading things about inflating fragmentes, back stack, stateSaved; I still don't know what to do in order the second activity to charge the fragment.

I try to be more especific: Detalle.java is a class that shows data refered to an item selected in MainActivity. That data is in the scrollview. Has to buttons to open other activities and a fragment to colect the opinions about the item. This fragment is also in the activity called Foto_detalle. It is suposed that both fragments shows the same info in a list (but that part don't bother me as much as the other, as we can be told to store the info in a database in the future. Also apreciate if someone could explain me how to do so).

xml from Detalle.java

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Detalle" >



<Button
    android:id="@+id/botonImagen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/botonLlamar"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/botonLlamar"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/botonLlamar"
    android:text="@string/botonImagen" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.comercio.Foto_detalle_fragmento"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="37dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/botonLlamar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nombreTienda"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="@string/nombreTienda"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/datosTienda"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/datosTienda"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:autoLink="web|email" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botonLlamar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
    android:text="@string/botonLlamar" />
```

Detalle.java

```
 package com.comercio;

 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v4.app.*;
 import android.text.util.Linkify;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class Detalle extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener{

TextView tnombre,tdatos;
static String tienda;
Datos datos;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle);
    cargarDatos();

    tienda = getIntent().getStringExtra("nombre");

    tnombre = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.nombreTienda);
    tnombre.setText(tienda);
    tdatos = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.datosTienda);
    Linkify.addLinks(tdatos, Linkify.ALL);
    tdatos.setText(datos.getDatos(tienda));
    Button llamar = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.botonLlamar);
    llamar.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button verImCom = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.botonImagen);
    verImCom.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void cargarDatos(){
    datos = new Datos(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tiendas),
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.direcciones),
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.telefonos),
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.horarios),
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.webs),
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.emails));
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    int componente = v.getId();
    switch(componente){
    case R.id.botonLlamar:
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:" + datos.getTelefono(tienda)));
        this.startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.botonImagen:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this,Foto_detalle.class);
        this.startActivity(intent2);
        break;
    }
  }


 }
```

xml de Foto_detalle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagenTienda"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/foto"
    android:src="@drawable/ccc" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentoComentario"
    android:name="com.comercios.Foto_detalle_fragmento"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imagenTienda"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imagenTienda"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imagenTienda" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Foto_detalle.java

```
package com.comercio;

 import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.*;
 import android.view.KeyEvent;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class Foto_detalle extends FragmentActivity {

private String tienda;
private ImageView imagenTienda;

protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    //si el fragmento ya está hinchado o en el backstack se coge
    setContentView(R.layout.foto_detalle);
    imagenTienda = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imagenTienda);
    tienda = Detalle.tienda;
    setImagenTienda(tienda);

}

public String getTienda() {
    return tienda;
}

private void setImagenTienda(String s){
    String [] nombreTiendas = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tiendas);
    int posicion=0;
    for(int i = 0;i<nombreTiendas.length;i++){
        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(nombreTiendas[i]))
            posicion=i;
    }
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("i"+String.valueOf(posicion), "drawable", "com.example.comercios"); 
    Drawable aux = getResources().getDrawable(resID);
    imagenTienda.setImageDrawable(aux);
}

/*
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        event.startTracking();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.isTracking()
            && !event.isCanceled()) {
        //se supone que al pulsar el botón de ir hacia atrás no carga al back Stack el fragmento
      /*  FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragmento = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentoComentario);
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentoComentario,fragmento);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();*/
       /* return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}*/


 }
```

xml of the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragmentoComentariolayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagenComentario"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/foto_tienda"
    android:src="@drawable/chat2" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listaComentarios"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imagenComentario"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagenComentario"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >
</ListView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editComentario"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listaComentarios"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listaComentarios"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" 
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:hint="@string/hint_edittext_comentario"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botonComentario"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editComentario"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imagenComentario"
    android:text="@string/botonComentario" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Foto_detalle_fragmento.java

```
package com.comercio;

import java.util.*;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;

public class Foto_detalle_fragmento  extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

private String tienda;
private ListView listaComentarios;
private EditText editaComentarios;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador;
//private ArrayList<CharSequence> valores;
private ArrayList<String> valores;
private Button botonComentario;
//private Bundle savedState = null;

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tienda = MainActivity.tiendaSeleccionada;
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.foto_detalle_fragmento, container, false);
    listaComentarios = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listaComentarios);
    editaComentarios = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editComentario);
    botonComentario = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.botonComentario);



    return view;
}

 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);   
     //quizás poner aquí lo de guardar el estado del fragment
 }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(!editaComentarios.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        valores.add(editaComentarios.getText().toString());
        Comentario.guardarComentario(tienda, editaComentarios.getText().toString());
        adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
        editaComentarios.setText("");
    }
}


}
```

This is the error log:

```
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.comercio/com.comercio.Foto_detalle}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at com.comercio.Foto_detalle.onCreate(Foto_detalle.java:18)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     ... 11 more
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.comercio-1.apk]
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
11-21 11:01:48.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     ... 20 more
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Foto_detalle_fragmento  extends FragmentActivity

Comment: Foto_detalle_fragmento is the class that make the fragment visible. That's why it extends from Fragment. The Activities are the only ones that should extend FragmentActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've found the error. It has nothing to do with inflating the fragment whilts it's the image in Foto_detalle.java the one that caused the error.

```
private void setImagenTienda(String s){
String [] nombreTiendas = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tiendas);
int posicion=0;
for(int i = 0;i<nombreTiendas.length;i++){
    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(nombreTiendas[i]))
        posicion=i;
}
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("i"+String.valueOf(posicion), "drawable", "com.example.comercios"); 
Drawable aux = getResources().getDrawable(resID);
imagenTienda.setImageDrawable(aux);
```

}

was wrong. Changing the way to grab the foto's ID was the quid:

```
private void setImagenTienda(String s){
    String [] nombreTiendas = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tiendas);
    int posicion=0;
    for(int i = 0;i<nombreTiendas.length;i++){
        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(nombreTiendas[i]))
            posicion=i;
    }
    String sAux = "i"+String.valueOf(posicion);
    int resID = this.getResources().getIdentifier(sAux, "drawable", this.getPackageName()); 
    Drawable aux = getResources().getDrawable(resID);
    imagenTienda.setImageDrawable(aux);
}
```

Thanks to Festus Tamakloe's responde to the cuestion [Using Android getIdentifier()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488238/using-android-getidentifier)