# Android: Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier returns java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, resources

I'm tring to get an id of the picture by name
`someId = "hd_2"`
`Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(someId, "drawable", getPackageName());`

```
public static final class drawable {
    ...
    public static final int hd_2=0x7f020088;
    ...
}
```

Why it might return java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Invalid method?

update:

I moved `Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier` from onCreate to onStart, now it returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getSystem()) on `Resources.getSystem()`:

> Return a global shared Resources object that provides access to only system resources (no application resources), and is not configured for the current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based on orientation, etc).

You are looking in the wrong `Resources` object. You need to get the instance from your current `Context`. Something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Resources res = getResources();
    int resId = res.getIdentifier(someId, "drawable", getPackageName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15488321/3633665

```
int resId=YourActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier("res_name", "drawable", YourActivity.this.getPackageName());
```