# Android/Java streamline display methods

Tags: java, android

Morning!

I am very new to learning android and indeed Java, I am building an app to track rugby scores for a match between two teams.  It works fine, but I'm annoyed by come of the code I have written.  Basically, I am calling a different method for each onClick - which I guess is fine, but each of those methods calls 2 different display methods, which I am looking to streamline if I can.

Example:

```
public void try_home(View v) {
    scoreHome += 5;
    tryHome++;
    displayForTeamA(scoreHome);
    displayTryHome(tryHome);
}
```

And my reset is even worse:

```
public void reset(View v) {
    displayForTeamA(scoreHome = 0);
    displayForTeamB(scoreAway = 0);
    displayTryHome(tryHome = 0);
    displayTryAway(tryAway = 0);
    displayConvertHome(convertHome = 0);
    displayConvertAway(convertAway = 0);
    displayFieldHome(fieldHome = 0);
    displayFieldAway(fieldAway = 0);
    displayPenHome(penHome = 0);
    displayPenAway(penAway = 0);

}
```

So this is what I am trying to do, but obviously doesn't work because findViewById() want's an int.. am I on the right track, is there a way to do this?

```
public void display(int val, String textView) {
    String viewID = "R.id." + textView;
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(viewID);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(val));
}
```

Hopefully I am making sense and my question is concise enough!
Thank you in advance for any and all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int viewID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(textView, "id", context.getPackageName())
```

should do the trick (replacing the first line inside your `display` method).

Comment: awesome! what is context? I dont have a var for that, and I assume the textview is the string im passing to the method? Thank you!

Comment: Where is the `display` method located? If it is inside your `Activity` just use `this` instead of `context`, if it is somewhere else it need a reference to your `Activity`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15488321/3356270

Comment: ah, wonderful, yeah I only have one class, the MainActivity, thanks again! (Can't  +1 your answer because noob, sorry)

Comment: Kind of irrelevant, but now I can do that, going to see if I can pass an array and loop, so only need one display() call (for learning purposes)

Comment: You cannot upvote my answer, but you can accept it as the correct answer: just click the check.